# SqlCommand with where clause backslashes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

There is a matching record in the DB for `DESKTOP-123\\markj`. When I execute the code in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns one record.

```
DECLARE @User NVARCHAR(260) = 'DESKTOP-123\\markj'

SELECT r.RoleName 
FROM dbo.WindowsAuthenticationRole war 
JOIN dbo.[Role] r ON r.RoleId = war.RoleId 
WHERE war.[User] = @User
```

However this C# code returns 0 records

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT r.RoleName FROM dbo.WindowsAuthenticationRole war JOIN dbo.[Role] r ON r.RoleId = war.RoleId WHERE war.[User] = @User", connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = @"DESKTOP-123\\markj";
```

How can I get the SQL command in C# to work?

**Update**

The responses helped me troubleshoot, I actually had the value saved in the DB with two slashes.

Comment: `There is a matching record in the DB for "DESKTOP-123\markj".` ← You are using the `@` symbol so you only should use one backslash as it is no longer escaped. `@"DESKTOP-123\markj";`

Comment: Likewise in Sql Server you do not escape backslash at all in a string (varchar/nvarchar or char nchar). `DECLARE @User NVARCHAR(260) = 'DESKTOP-123\markj'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use either @ without escaping the backslash.. or escape it without @

```
command.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = @"DESKTOP-123\markj";

//or
command.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "DESKTOP-123\\markj";
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#how-to-use-escape-sequences-in-an-interpolated-string) on string interpolation.